# Simple User's Guide / Tutorial for Apache httpd?

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd

Is there a simple user guide or tutorial for Apache httpd?  I find that the official documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/) is a little hard to navigate and learn from if you're not up to speed with a lot of the basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be best to start with a specific thing with Apache that you want to/need to accomplish. Otherwise Amazon, Borders and Barnes and Noble are your friends!

There is an Apache for Dummies book too (no offense!)

Things that might be helpful:

http://bytes.com/serveradministration/webservers/apache/theapachewebserver/page1.html

Also, each OS might implement Apache a bit differently as far as where it is stored, default settings, etc. Linux does differently than Windows for example.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if this is your first experience with Apache, and if you are just experimenting, you could start with something easier like lighttpd: http://www.lighttpd.net/

Comment: +1 was about to say the same thing. Apache configuration is a beast!

Answer (score 0):

The docs can look a bit daunting because Apache is so powerful and flexible, which has its price. I agree with indiecompanyllc in that you should select something specific to start with but rather than invest in books, which tend to be limited, costly and out of date, I recommend Googling. Just bear in mind that most tasks can be performed more than one way, so read more than one article on the same topic if you find the going a bit heavy.